# Quick way to find apis corresponding to API levels in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

My project targets minimum api level of API 21. I am trying to use LocalDateTime to fetch current date but get a warning saying your minimum api level is 21 and LocalDateTime is in API level 28.

Is there a way to quickly find APIs corresponding to a given level somewhere on web or in Android studio? I am coding in kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to figure out the api level by your self, just use a support library.

**Use a [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library):**

> When developing apps that support multiple API versions, you may want a standard way to provide newer features on earlier versions of Android or gracefully fall back to equivalent functionality.

**Beware that:**

> With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components.